# How to hide keyboard trhough out application?

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

what I am trying to do is hide the keyboard and just show it when any edittext has focus, other wise do not show it, but I intent to implement it in the entire application.

In a single activity I use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Is there a way to implement such thing but to the entire app? Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Common practice to create an abstract BaseActivity class where you can override onCreate method and call this code. Every Activity based from BaseActivity will call toggleSoftInput method.

For example:

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }
}
```

And all Activities need to extends from BaseActivity instead of AppCompatActivity, for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Very important to call super.

Comment: thanks for the reply. could you elavorate a little more?

Comment: I added an example to the answer for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out